# Most efficient way to query Django model by distinct groups and iterate over those subset queries

Tags: django, django-queryset

Database is MySQL
I am trying to iterate over all of the fields in my model by grouping them by the `date_created` field and iterating over each query. I have been able to do so but my method seems inefficient. Is there a better, cleaner way? The database is expected to reach north of 50,000 rows with unique dates up to and past a year long. I plan on doing intricate work within each query of `date_created` sub queries and will need access to other fields in the model. I plan on using the data mostly to display charts and stuff on a webpage using Django and Heroku.

```
    data = model.objects.all()

    distinct_dates = data.values('date_created').distinct()

    for each_date in distinct_dates:
        data.filter(date_created=each_date['date_created'])
```

The values of `each_date` would be each unique date associated with the model and that field

Here is my model

```
class Model(models.Model):
    expansion = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', db_index=True)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    date_created = models.DateField(db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['date_created', ]
```

Comment: Can you show us your models?

Comment: Check my answer @juju. If you can add more details to your question, I can update my answer.

Comment: @GrandPhuba I added more information to my problem. Reading your current solution has been helpful in understanding that my solution may not be very efficient but yeah I would be doing intricate work with each instance of each subquery of dates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on many factors, a few of which are the following:

1. The database you are using
2. The network in between the database and your application
3. The number of rows of data
4. The number of unique dates in your data set
5. What you plan to do with the data afterwards
6. Details about the application

Consider the following use cases:

1. If all you are doing is fetching the data and do nothing with it, then most of the time fetching all of the data at once is faster.

```
data = model.objects.all()
```

2. If you plan to just get aggregated values per date, then it's faster to do the following:

```
data_by_dates = model.order_by('date_created').values(
    'date_created'
).annotate(
    count=Count('date_created'), total=Sum('amount')
)
```

3. If you have data for thousands of dates, but the data only a few rows per date, and you collect the rows by date, then you'll be connecting to the db a million times as well.
4. If you have data for say just 7 days, but there's like a data point per second in that date, then you'll get 86400 data points, but only connect to the db 7 times
5. If you have data for say a year, and you have a data point per second, and you decide to collect ALL of them at once, then that will eat up a lot of server memory. If you plan to process that data in pure python, then that will eat up your CPU as well.

I could come up with many more use-cases, but unless you know what you are actually trying to do, and you know the context involved, it would be hard to say what the "most efficient" way is.